# download csv file dat from github

Tags: python, csv, file, github, download

I am trying to download data from a csv file in github to a data frame
code:
import pandas as pd
url = "https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/linear_regression_class/data_2d.csv"
r = requests.get(url+file)
pd.read_csv(url,names = ['X1','X2','y'])

Instead of loading file data it seems that the html page data is stored in the dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV0h0.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/linear_regression_class/data_2d.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])

print df.head(5)
```